# Yocto - use specific layer in recipe

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I have two (almost identical 3rd party) layers, lets call them `meta-version1` and `meta-version2` and two recipes in my own layer, lets call them `recipeA` and `recipeB`.

Is it possible to specify in the recipes on which layer they depend so that `inherit` and `DEPENDS` are using the specified layer? So that `recipeA` is using only the components of `meta-version1` and `recipeB` is only using the components of `meta-version2`.

Comment: I think what you ask for is pretty hard to configure. I'd choose a simpler solution with removing or adding the path to the layer you need to use in the `bblayers.conf` file.

Comment: I agree with @Antoni, I also suggest that you either change the names in meta-version1 and meta-version2, because for `DEPENDS` it will look for the first recipe in the layer with higher priority, and you cannot make it happen for both recipes.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In the end we had to rename the recipes in meta-version1 in a way that they where distinguishable from meta-version2.